# What are the max amount of items that can be placed in Mario Maker?

Tags: super-mario-maker

What is the maximum amount of enemies, doors, and teleport pipes that you can place in Mario Maker? I have ran into the issue before where I cannot place any more enemies. I have a great idea for a level but I do not want to have to stop short since this will require a lot of time to create. The floor blocks do not seem to have a limit....if there is, please correct me. Take in to consideration the extra screen once you unlock the ability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a combined maximum of 2000 for the following items:

- Brick Block/Rotating Block
- ? Block
- Solid Block
- Ground Tile
- Coin
- Spike Trap/Jellectro/small Urchins
- Jump Block/Music Block
- Donut Block
- Cloud Block
- Hidden ? Block
- Tracks

---

There is a combined maximum of 200 for the following items, however, the size can be adjusted without problem:

- Pipe
- Semi-Solid Platform
- Bridges
- Vine
- Mushroom Platform

---

There is a combined maximum of 100 for the following items:

- Super Mushroom
- Mystery Mushroom/Raccoon Leaf/Cape Feather/Propeller Mushroom
- Fire Flower
- Super Star
- 1-Up Mushroom

---

There is a combined maximum of 100 for the following items:

- Trampoline
- Goomba
- Koopa Troopa
- Piranha Plant/Fire Piranha Plants/Jumping Piranha Plant
- Lakitu/Lakitu's Cloud (only Lakitu counts as 2 against the limit)
- Spiny/Spiny Helmet
- Platform/Loose Platform
- Bill Blaster/Red Homing Bill Blaster
- Blooper/Blooper Nannies
- Cheep Cheep
- Hammer Bro/Sledge Bro
- Buzzy Beetle/Buzzy Beetle helmet/Parabeetle
- Thwomp
- Lava Bubble/Podoboo
- Skull Raft/Bone Lift
- Fire Bar
- Rocky Wrench/Monty Mole
- Bob-Omb
- POW Block
- Rocket Engine
- Cannon
- Spike Top
- Boo/Circling Boo Buddies/Stretch
- Dry Bones/Fishbones
- Magikoopa
- P-Switch
- Muncher
- Wiggler
- Yoshi/Goomba's Shoe
- Koopa Clown Car
- Grinder
- Chain Chomp
- One-way Wall

---

Additionally, there is a maximum of:

- 100 Arrows
- 4 sets of Doors (8 doors in total)
- 3 Bowsers/Bowser Jr. in total

---

Items or enemies that have been put into blocks don't count against any limit.

Items or Enemies that have been put into pipes do count against their respective limits.

These limits are per level, and the limits count seperately for the level and sub-level.

Finally, A maximum of 10 pipes can be turned into a set of warp pipes, meaning there can be up to 10 connections between the regular level and the sublevel.

---

Source: [Pushing the Object Limit in Super Mario Maker!](https://youtu.be/MIGRg1DLwi8) video by GameXplain, groups manually verified by me.